# FramerJS - How to Reset or Refresh Prototype from code, without reloading?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototyping, framerjs

How to reset a FramerJS prototype programatically (through code)?

I have defined a layer on clicking of which I want the prototype to reset to its initial state. I have tried using `location.reload()` but that reloads from network. How to reset without reloading the prototype from network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling `Framer.CurrentContext.reset()` and rebuilding your prototype.

To make this easy, write all your setup code inside a function that you call after resetting the context. Remember to also call the `setup()` function for the initial setup.

Example:

```
setup = ->
    # Everything should go inside the setup() function
    layerA = new Layer
        backgroundColor: 'green'

    layerA.animate
        properties:
            x: Align.right

    resetButton = new Layer
        x: Align.center
        y: Align.bottom
        backgroundColor: 'red'

    resetButton.onClick ->
        Framer.CurrentContext.reset()
        #Call setup() again to recreate all layers
        setup() 

# Initial setup call
setup()
```

Full prototype here: http://share.framerjs.com/9fl1g7icvnax/